# Mule 4 How to setup 'Datasource Reference Connection' to talk to DB2 along with jks

Tags: db2, mule4, cloudhub

I need to setup Mule 4 hosted in Cloudhub to talk to DB2 resides on our internal server. I need to pass certificate .jks and password along with db connection. Can anyone explain how can this be done. If possible share some code snippet.

Answer (score -1):

I did try below MuleSoft Official article from KB and it is working like a charm.

https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-connect-to-a-DB-using-SSL-and-a-connection-datasource-in-Mule-4